# Sort multimedinsional array with dynamic key name

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort a php array whose key value combination is dynamic thus making it difficult to define a function and apply usort()
Here is the array

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [PAYE] => 43 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [VAT] => 2 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [NHIF] => 1 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [NSSF] => 2 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [MPESA] => 1 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [EQUITEL] => 1 ) 
    [6] => Array ( [AIRTEL] => 1 ) 
    [7] => Array ( [CER] => 2 ) 
    [8] => Array ( [BDD] => 4 ) 
    [9] => Array ( [BMI] => 1 ) 
    [10] => Array ( [TG] => 7 ) 
    [11] => Array ( [BT] => 3 ) 
    [12] => Array ( [EPL] => 4 ) 
    [13] => Array ( [KPL] => 8 ) 
)
```

I want to sort the array using the right most value. The result should be

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [PAYE] => 43 ) 
    [13] => Array ( [KPL] => 8 )
    [10] => Array ( [TG] => 7 ) 
    [8] => Array ( [BDD] => 4 ) 
    [12] => Array ( [EPL] => 4 )
    [11] => Array ( [BT] => 3 )
    [7] => Array ( [CER] => 2 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [NSSF] => 2 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [VAT] => 2 )
    [3] => Array ( [NSSF] => 2 ) 
    [6] => Array ( [AIRTEL] => 1 ) 
    [9] => Array ( [BMI] => 1 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [MPESA] => 1 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [NHIF] => 1 ) 
)
```

How should I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `uasort` function to save keys and `array_shift` to take values to compare

```
uasort($array, function($i1, $i2) {  
                  return array_shift($i2) - array_shift($i1); });

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

`uasort` and `current` functions will do the job:

```
// $arr is your initial array
uasort($arr, function($a, $b){   // will maintain index association
    return current($b) - current($a);
});
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php